# Singleton: How do I instance a Singleton for the first time?

Tags: c#, singleton

I have this singleton class:

```
public class Utente
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Utente> lazy =
    new Lazy<Utente>(() => new Utente());

    public static Utente Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazy.Value;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int issuperuser { get; set; }
    public string persontype { get; set; }
    public int idpersontype { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string[] permissions { get; set; }
    public List<Mese> mese { get; set; }
}
```

and I need to instance lazy for the first time. How do I do that? I need to instance the class for the first time to have it saved on the whole rest of the program.

Now I need to use this in this class:

```
Utente u = new Utente();
WebRequest richiesta = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
WebResponse risposta = (HttpWebResponse)CreateLoginRequest(richiesta).GetResponse();
StreamReader dati = new StreamReader(risposta.GetResponseStream());
string output = dati.ReadToEnd();
u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Utente>(output);
risposta.Close();
```

Is the `Utente()` correct or should I use another code?
EDIT:

```
Utente u = new Utente();
WebRequest richiesta = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
WebResponse risposta = (HttpWebResponse)CreateLoginRequest(richiesta).GetResponse();
StreamReader dati = new StreamReader(risposta.GetResponseStream());
string output = dati.ReadToEnd();
u = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Utente>(output);
risposta.Close();
```

That class Utente needs to be instanciated only one time so that i can use that values in all the program. So why if i do this in another class:`

```
if (verifica && (Utente.Instance.persontype == "Datore"))
```

Utente.Instance.persontype results as null?

Comment: `new Lazy<Utente>(() => new Utente());` already does it. You should create default private constructor to prevent another instance being instanciated.

Comment: i mean in other classes. if i try to call Instance it always return null

Comment: Please add problem description to your question. If you have error - add error details. If you have unexpected results, then please describe your results, expected results, and add some code to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First problem: you haven't disabled `Utente` class instances creation via the public constructor. The first line of your code creates a new instance:

```
Utente u = new Utente();
```

As others already mentioned, you have to disable creating new instances of singleton class outside of this class. Make the constructor private:

```
private Utente() { }
```

Now the second problem - you want to fill properties of the singleton with Newtonsoft JSON deserializer. *Even if the constructor is private, the deserializer will create a new instance of Utrente class* each time you deserialize some string:

```
var newInstance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Utente>(output); // 'output' is json string
```

So you should not use `DeserializeObject` method. You should use [`PopulateObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PopulateObject.htm) method and pass already existing instance of singleton to be filled by Newtonsoft JSON:

```
JsonConvert.PopulateObject(output, Utente.Instance);
```

---

And small note - you don't need `set` method for `Instance` property of singleton. With C# 6 Expression-Bodied members you can simplify this property to:

```
public static Utente Instance => lazy.Value;
```

Comment: So after i populated the lazy i have still the same problem: Utente.Instance.persontype is still null

Comment: @LorenzoValenti that is impossible. Either you don't use `PopulateObject` as described above, or JSON string don't have `persontype` value

Comment: i'm sure that the persontype is in the string but still i get the null in the persontype field

Comment: @LorenzoValenti then you use DeserializeObject instead of PopulateObject

Comment: i'm using this: JsonConvert.PopulateObject(output, Utente.lazy);

Comment: @LorenzoValenti why? there is no `JsonConvert.PopulateObject(output, Utente.lazy)` in my answer

Comment: yeah, i failed writing the code, sorry about that and thank you. this works

Comment: @LorenzoValenti good that we found the issue :) Keep in mind that `DeserializeObject` will create new instance even if constructor is private

Answer (score 0):

You already have instantiated the lazy, it is instantiated in this line:

```
private static readonly Lazy<Utente> lazy = new Lazy<Utente>(() => new Utente());
```

Whenever you call `.Value` on the lazy, it will make sure the constuctor is called and the instance stored and returned. From your code, the lazy can't ever return `null`.

Side note: you generally have no setter in the singleton pattern, it should self-initialize.

The problem in your code is that you are making a new instance: `Utente u = new Utente();` from outside the singleton class. That is how how singleton works. You should only access `Utente.Instance`. You can prevent instantiating instances from outside by add a private constructor to your `Utente` class:

```
private Utente
{ }
```

From your current code it seems you shouldn't use the singleton pattern at all, since you are trying to deserialize it from a JSON stream: there can be multiple instances.

Comment: Then it's not clear what kind of problem we are solving :)

Comment: It seems OP is trying to instantiate the singleton using `Utente u = new Utente();` in the calling code, which doesn't seem alright to me.

Answer (score 0):

Change your class:

```
public class Utente
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Utente> lazy =
    new Lazy<Utente>(() => new Utente());

    // private C'tor - prevent from other to create your class
    private Utente() { }
    // Give access to your instnace
    public static Utente Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What has changed?

Comment: @PatrickHofman private constructor was added. But again, it's not clear whether it solves OP problem, because its unclear what is the problem :)

Comment: and change the intance property to be public instead of private

Answer (score 0):

Here you are doing it wrong

```
Utente u = new Utente();
```

instead of instantiating the `Utente` use

```
Utente u = Utente.Instance;
```

Moreever you should define private constructor so that you can prevent another instance being instanciated.

```
public class Utente
{
    private Utente(){} //override default public constructor.
    private static readonly Lazy<Utente> lazy =
    new Lazy<Utente>(() => new Utente());

    public static Utente Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazy.Value;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int issuperuser { get; set; }
    public string persontype { get; set; }
    public int idpersontype { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string[] permissions { get; set; }
    public List<Mese> mese { get; set; }
}
```